# Basic JS - Declaring require var and using inside class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JS class declared as such:

```
class Useful {
  someFunction(index) {
    //Does something with index
}
```

However I'm unsure what the best practice is to declare require variables such as `var fs = require('fs')` and how to use it - namely:

- Should `var fs = require('fs')` be inside the `class` declaration or outside it
- And then to use it would I use `this`

Thanks.

UPDATE - following comments - is this correct

```
const fs = require('fs')

    class Useful {
      someFunction(index) {
        //Does something with index
        fs.writeFile(......)
    }
```

Comment: variable declarations inside the class block are not allowed ( for now). Put it before, and always use `const`. How do you want to access fs?

Comment: @Jonasw i want to use `fs` inside a function within that class
```createNewUser(token) {
////Use fs.writefile here```

Comment: yeah then put it outside of the class declaration and youre done.

Comment: A module import should be done in the top scope of the file, not within the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A

```
class Useful {
  someFunction(index) {
     const fs = require("fs");
  }
}
```

> B

```
const fs = require("fs");
class Useful {
  someFunction(index) {

  }
}
```

Theres an important difference between these two: In A, fs will be loaded every time *someFunction* is called. This is bad for performance and has no real advantage. So use B.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. Also say I had something like `const nUser = require('../helpers/newUserCreator')` And that `newUserCreator` file had this:
```module.exports = {
createNewUsers: function(numberOfAccountsToCreate) { .... }``` How would I correctly call that function `createNewUsers`

Comment: @userMod2 maybe `nUser.createNewUsers()` ?!

Comment: In node.js module is loaded only once, all other requires are from cache. So there is only one difference between A and B, in the first case module will be loaded, when `someFunction` is called.

Comment: @alexmac theres still a module lookup. And even if that overhead is small, i prefer long startup time instead of long first request ping.

Answer (score 1):

1) All module require declarations should ideally be at the top of the file.

```
const useful = require('useful')

class foo ....
```

2) 'this' refers to the class itself and so you need to explicitly attach the module you just imported inside the class constructor as a class property if you need it like that

```
class Useful (importedModule) {
    constructor(importedModule) { // constructor syntactic sugar
        this.module = importedModule;
    }
```

3) With es6 you can also import your modules with

```
import somethingUseful from 'module_or_./filePath_where_something_useful_is_kept'
```

4) with es6 let and const are much better alternatives to var.